# Cannot get value of session from redis

Tags: redis

I'm trying to get a value from redis to see what value is stored against a session (using `express-session`).

If I do:

```
❯ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "sess:NhtX2aESQFU3YAqfaKawNWC7FS6GY9SM"
2) "sess:DkVqgapP6dwrAElp0AENKY1j1iTDHbxz"
127.0.0.1:6379> GET "sess:DkVqgapP6dwrAElp0AENKY1j1iTDHbxz"
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> GET 'sess:DkVqgapP6dwrAElp0AENKY1j1iTDHbxz'
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> GET `sess:DkVqgapP6dwrAElp0AENKY1j1iTDHbxz`
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

I'm sure it's something basic I'm doing wrong. I've used different delimiters (single/double quotes, etc.) but can't get anything. Is it the datatype of what's stored there??

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for this. Are the keys being SET have TTL associated with them? Maybe by the time you are trying to fetch the key - they are expiring. In your express app are you explicitly deleting the keys or setting an expiry on them?

Comment: It looks like that's the case actually. I think the default session time was set to expire in under 1 minute.